# How to keep the PostgreSQL path in environment variable forever?

Tags: windows, postgresql, cmd, path, psql

I install PostgerSQL on Windows. I also added the bin and lib to PATH, using the following command:

```
cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin
set path=%PATH%;%CD%
setx path "%PATH%"
```

Then, I check the psql version by `psql --version` command, and it display:

```
WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
```

Then, I check the the path using `echo "%PATH%"` and I see the path `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin` with all other paths.

**However, each time I close the cmd and open it again the PostgreSQL path is removed** while all other paths are still there, and the command `psql --version` is not recognized.

```
'psql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I need the path to be there always I cannot add the path each time I open the cmd.

How could I add the PostgreSQL path to the environment variables **forever**? because I need to use psql with Git Bash also.

Why the the PostgreSQL path is removed while all other path are there?

I already looked in many questions here and apply the solutions, but still I have this problem.

***NOTE:  I already added the node.js path using the same commands and it works for node.js, but not work for PostgreSQL***

Comment: The system or user environment variables need to be edited. Bring up Settings, type `environment` into the 'Find a setting' edit control, then edit the PATH variable.

Comment: I only  used set path=%CD%;%PATH%  alone without setx and I have the same problem. Note: I used the same commands to add Node.js to environment variables. It works for Node.js, but not for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to `Advanced system settings > [Environment Variables...] > System variables > Path > [Edit...]` and append your path to that list.

The variable you set via `setx` is only stored for current shell session. But with that via system you will set it forever.

> instruction with screenshots [can be found here](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/)

Comment: I do not have administrative permission to access the Advance system settings, I can only set it through cmd.

Comment: @agaios: then change the path for **your** account.  https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/windows-10/113/windows-10-set-path.html

Comment: I did both set and setx as the link describe, but still having the issue. Also, I already added the node.js path using the same command and it works for node.js, but not work for PostgreSQL